# What is this filming technique called and how do I do it?

Tags: effects, filming

I hope I'm in the right forum for this question!

Basically, I'm trying to create [this effect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViLDPBaIO-E#t=0m20s), where the camera zooms in on Simba's face and the background seems to zoom in at a different pace.

I'd like to know, first, what this effect is called. I want to see if I can recreate it in the opposite way. So basically, I want to make it seem like I'm zooming out in the same way this effect is zooming in.

Second, I'd like to know where I can find out how to do this. I'm really a complete n00b at filming and I don't have any fancy filming material, just a basic camera that can record. I'd love some suggestions. :) Thanks a ton!

Comment: your lion king video (it was, I recall from memory [iirc](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=iirc)) link is gone (trolled by copyright trolls). could you link another example or make a gif? (if possible, would be big extra, be it [creative commons](https://www.youtube.com/creativecommons) lic-ed, [which helps protect against](http://free-culture.cc/) stealing away our rights of fair use by big companies and their harm against humanity and the environment..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [dolly zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom), and you achieve it by moving the camera towards your subject and zooming out at the same time (or moving away and zooming in).

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!! It was driving me nuts to know what it was, haha.